# Prolog Lists - Finding items with multiple constraints

Tags: list, prolog, constraints

I need to write a prolog program "dump." that can get data from a database with constraints:

Imagine this simple database a(Int,Color)

```
a(1,blue).
a(1,red).
a(1,green).
a(2,green).
a(3,yellow).
a(3,blue).
a(4,green).
a(4,purple).
a(4,blue).
a(4,red).
```

I need my program "dump." to give me all the Int elements that are related to the Color 'blue' and 'red' and is related to any other color and only output the color that is not blue and red. an example query would be

```
?- dump.
1 green
4 purple 
4 green
true
```

Here i would not care to know that 3 is related to yellow because 3 is not related to both blue and red.

Can anyone help me? :)

Comment: What means: "that are related to the Color 'blue' and 'red'"?

Comment: Just that 1 can have the color blue, red and green and so on. i was not sure how to put it ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, stick to pure relations! There is no need to print things, for Prolog does the printing for you.

```
redblue_number(Nr) :-
   a(Nr, red),
   a(Nr, blue).

nr_related(Nr, Related) :-
   redblue_number(Nr),
   dif(Related, red),
   dif(Related, blue),
   a(Nr, Related).

?- nr_related(Nr, Related).
   Nr = 1, Related = green
;  Nr = 4, Related = green
;  Nr = 4, Related = purple
; false.
```

Comment: Thanks. That is close to what i came up with, but i am asked to solve it with a program that takes no arguments and displays it in that exact format specified in the test query even if it seems odd for prolog to force it to print. Do you think this is possible ?

Comment: `dump :- \+ ( nr_related(Nr, Related), \+ ( write(Nr), write(' '), write(Related), nl ) ).` But that's very bad to do for a beginner! Stick to pure relations

Comment: I guess the course i am doing this exercise for is not exactly a beginners course since i did manage to solve it similar to you... But it sounds like you would consider this short statement as bad practice?, or is it just considered as "not for beginners" ?
This is of cause just a print of what the previous code found, i guess what i am asked to do is avoiding the need of the redblue_number/1 and nr_related/2

Comment: What is problematic is that you are required to print things. That is, that you need to produce side effects right in the beginning.  It really makes no sense to avoid the auxiliary relations! Even worse, that will obscure a lot of things

Comment: I agree that it seems stupid. I guess i am asked this to challenge us for some reason.
The small dump function you gave seems to only print a true. I am not so strong in the use of negation-as-failure yet as it is what i am learning at the moment so i am not sure why it only prints true.

Answer (score 0):

Try something this:

```
dump :-
  a(X,C)                     , % find an int/color pair
  related_to_red_and_blue(X) , % - such that the int is related to both red and blue, and
  not_red_or_blue(C)         , % - such that the color is not red or blue itself.
  dump(X,C)                  , % - log to the console
  fail                       . % - fail, inducing backtracking to find the next solution, 
dump.                          % and finally, succeed.

related_to_red_and_blue(X) :- a(X,red) , a(X,blue) .

not_red_or_blue(C) :- C \= red , C \= blue .
```

It does rather make the assumption that no color is related to the same integer more than once. It will also **always** succeed, even if nothing matches the constraints.

You could also do something like this, reusing the above `related_to_red_and_blue/1` and `not_red_or_blue/1` predicates:

```
dump :-
  setof( X:C , ( a(X,C) , related_to_red_and_blue(X) , not_red_or_blue(C) ) , Matches ) ,
  dump(Matches)
  .

dump( [] ) .
dump( [X:C|Ms] ) :-
  write(X) ,
  write(' ') ,
  write(C) ,
  nl ,
  dump(Ms)
  .
```

The above

- uses `setof/3` to find the distinct set of pairs matching the constraints.
- recursively dumps them to the console
- succeeds.

It will fail if nothing matches the constraints.